# ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 304: Route [login] not defined. (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\school\resources\views\login.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel-5

hello i am just start on laravel . i found ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 304:

Route [login] not defined. (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\school\resources\views\login.blade.php) error  what can i do

```
Route::get('/' , ['as' => '/', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getlogin']);
Route::post('/Login', ['as'=> 'Login' , 'uses' => 'LoginController@postLogin' ]);
Route::group(['middleware'=>['authen','roles' ]], function(){   
Route::get('/logout' , ['as' => 'logout' , 'uses'=> 'LoginController@getLogout']);
Route::get('/dashboard',['as'=> 'dashboard', 'uses'=> 'DashboardController@dashboard']);
```

Comment: Have you tried `Route::post('/login'...` with lowercase L?

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/' , ['as' => '/', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getlogin']);
Route::post('/Login', ['as'=> 'Login' , 'uses' => 'LoginController@postLogin']);
```

`'as' => '/'` and `'as' => 'Login'`
so if you want to access the login post page, you should use the route by its name.. `Login` or `/`

or even rename your route in `routes.php` as `login`

> **Note:** `Routes` names are Case Sensitive